# Exclude page from restriction

Tags: wordpress

I am using this plugin called Restricted Site Access : https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/restricted-site-access/

So want to exclude a specific page from restriction. So all the users can access it. The Page id is 3081. I found the below code but that checks the feed and not page.

```
add_filter( 'restricted_site_access_is_restricted', 'my_rsa_feed_override’, 10, 2 );

function my_rsa_feed_override( $is_restricted, $wp ) {
    // check query variables to see if this is the feed
    if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['feed'] ) ) {
        $is_restricted = false;
    }
    return $is_restricted;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `feed` use the `page_id` attribute:

```
if ( $wp->query_vars['page_id'] == 3081 ) {
    $is_restricted = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,So have added the code :add_filter( 'restricted_site_access_is_restricted', 'my_rsa_feed_override', 10, 2 );

function my_rsa_feed_override( $is_restricted, $wp ) {
    // check query variables to see if this is the feed
 if ( $wp->query_vars['page_id'] == 3081 ) {
  $is_restricted = false;
 }
    return $is_restricted;
}.....But this is not working

Comment: try `return false;` and comment out if condition and check if it works or not.

Comment: Have you commented if condition?

Comment: @Vinz If you have added `return false;` at the end then all the pages will be excluded. Can you verify that `$wp->query_vars['page_id']` outputs `3081`.

Comment: Yes after adding return false excluded all the pages. How to verify page id? I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200939/discussion-between-jainil-and-vinz).

Comment: Hi, how do i exclude multiple pages? I am using the below code for single page exclusion: add_filter( 'restricted_site_access_is_restricted', 'my_rsa_feed_override', 10, 2 );
function my_rsa_feed_override( $is_restricted, $wp ) {
    // check query variables to see if this is the feed
 if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "guest-home" ) {
 $is_restricted = false;
 }
    return $is_restricted;
}

Comment: @Vinz add the `OR` condition in the `if` condition like this: `if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && ( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "guest-home" || $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == "guest-home2" )  )`